# snmpwalk partially works, then returns a timeout. After the timeout, the walk does not work at all. What could be causing this?

Tags: windows-server-2008, snmp

I have sysedge running on two hosts for snmp. They have the same SNMP configuration in HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\SNMP exactly the same, but one host does not work. If I restart sysedge on the host, an snmpwalk works up to a point (at the HOST-RESOURCES-MIB) but hangs and returns a timeout after some time. After the timeout, the snmpwalk does not work unless I restart the service again (where it fails at the same point).

This is where it fails in the walk:

```
HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrSystemInitialLoadDevice.0 = INTEGER: 0
```

Also, before I start the walk, sysedge is using 00 CPU and about 5,000 K Memory. After I do the walk that times it out, it climbs to ~20,000 K, then bounces between 23,000 K and 41,000 K Memory usage.

Does anyone know what could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have debugging skills, contact the vendor.

If you want to debug, use [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/sysinternals/bb896645), [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/sysinternals/bb896653) and may be a debugger to find out what is happening.

Check also the disk I/O or if the disk is speed is fine. It could be a disk that is in a pre-fail state and that is becoming slow.

Check if you have mapped drives that are not answering.

Comment: I haven't done indepth debugging before, so I may have to find another solution. It looks like sysedge is using 250,000K Memory now, and jumping to 300,000K. I might have to kill the process

Comment: From the small amount of info you have, does this look like a config problem or a problem with the application itself?

Comment: I would expect to be a problem with the server is running on. I would start checking what is happening with the Windows server. I would try to see if I have the same issue with `procmon` and `wmi`.

Comment: `sysedge` is replacing the native SNMP, or is it a SNMP subagent?

Comment: it is a subagent